# Slide com troca de imagem de fundo da div mãe

Tags: javascript, slide

Galera, eu estou tentando fazer um *slide* que quando trocar de imagem troque também a *imagem de background* da `div "banner"` junto com a imagem do slide, alguém pode me ajudar?

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Testando slide</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.2.12/jquery.bxslider.css">
  </head>

<body>
<div class="banner" style="width: 700px; height:300px; padding: 60px;">
 <div class="slider" style="margin: auto;">
<div class="img-slider" data-color="1"><img src="imgs/1.jpg" width="600" height="250"/></div>
<div class="img-slider" data-color="2"><img src="imgs/2.jpg" width="600" height="250"/></div>
<div class="img-slider" data-color="3"><img src="imgs/3.jpg" width="600" height="250"/></div>
<div class="img-slider" data-color="4"><img src="imgs/4.jpg" width="600" height="250"/></div>
<div class="img-slider" data-color="5"><img src="imgs/5.jpg" width="600" height="250"/></div>
<div class="img-slider" data-color="6"><img src="imgs/6.jpg" width="600" height="250"/></div>
</div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.2.12/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>

 <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.slider').bxSlider({
    auto: true,
    stopAuto: true,
    slideWidth: 600,
    onSlideNext: function($slideElement, oldIndex, newIndex){
        var corSlide = $('.img-slider').eq( newIndex ).data('color');
        $('.banner').css({ 'background': 'url("imgs/' + corSlide + '.jpg") no-repeat fixed'});
    }
  });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Troque o callback `onSlideNext` por `onSlideAfter` e busque o `src` da imagem na div que contenha o atributo `aria-hidden="false"`. Irá substituir o fundo da div pela imagem que está sendo exibida:

Veja:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.slider').bxSlider({
    auto: true,
    stopAuto: true,
    slideWidth: 600,
    onSlideAfter: function(){
        var corSlide = $('.slider div[aria-hidden="false"] img').attr('src');
        $('.banner').css({ 'background': 'url(' + corSlide + ') no-repeat fixed'});
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.2.12/jquery.bxslider.css">
<div class="banner" style="width: 700px; height:300px; padding: 60px;">
   <div class="slider" style="margin: auto;">
      <div class="img-slider" data-color="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini"><img src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg" width="600" height="250"/></div>
      <div class="img-slider" data-color="https://tinyjpg.com/images/social/website"><img src="https://tinyjpg.com/images/social/website.jpg" width="600" height="250"/></div>
   </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.2.12/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
```